# Sign of a function that involves the arithmetic function that counts the number of Ramanujan primes less than a given integer

Tags: number-theory, inequality, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, experimental-mathematics

In this post we denote the arithmetic function that counts the number of Ramanujan $R$ primes less than $x$ as 
$$\pi_{_{R}}(x)=\#\{\text{Ramanujan primes }R\text{ such that }R\leq x\}$$
thus is the analogous for Ramanujan primes than the prime-counting function. Wikipedia has an article for [*Ramanujan prime.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_prime) A well-known conjecture in analytic number theory is the known as [*Second Hardy–Littlewood conjecture*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_conjecture) (the link also from Wikipedia, where were added references).

I hope that my question* is on topic, I am asking what about the sign of the following function or numerical support, general feedback about the sign of 
$$f(x,y)=\pi_{_{R}}(x)+\pi_{_{R}}(y)-\pi_{_{R}}(x+y)$$
for integers numbers $x\leq y$ (both integers) such that $x\geq x_0$ for a suitable constant $x_0\geq 2$.

> **Question.** I would like to know some feedback about the sign of $f(x,y)$ when the variables $x$ and $y$ run over positive integers $x_0\leq x$ and $x\leq y\leq N$ for a suitable and integer $x_0$ (if there is some interesting $x_0$, I don't know how oscillates our function) and $N$ also integer, a enough large integer $N$. I mean if you know how to provide me a theoretical reasoning, heuristic or well if you know it from the literature that answer this feedback as a reference request (if it is in the literature I try to search and read it from your recommentation). **Many thanks.**

Optionally (or alternatively if previous question isn't available because it is very difficult to get a reasoning about it), can you provide numerical evidence for the sign (or oscillations of the sign) of $f(x,y)$ for some $N$ for our lattice of intergers $x_0\leq x\leq y$ and $x\leq y\leq N$, to emphasize $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ and $x_0$ is a suitable positive integer?

I know just the more humble and simple examples.

**Examples.** *One has that* $$3=\pi_{_{R}}(17)=\pi_{_{R}}(8+9)<\pi_{_{R}}(8)+\pi_{_{R}}(9)=2+2=4.$$ *Other example is*  $$7=\pi_{_{R}}(64)=\pi_{_{R}}(17+47)<\pi_{_{R}}(17)+\pi_{_{R}}(47)=3+6=9.$$

---

*My problem is that I've tried to check what about a Second Hardy–Littlewood conjecture for the arithmetic function $\pi_{_{R}}(x)$ using a programming language but I had difficulties (I know and I can to test the Second Hardy–Littlewood conjecture for the classical prime-counting function and for a given finite segment(s) of integers but in our case, the calculations with a computer that I need to know to get certain computation evidence involving $\pi_{_{R}}(x)$, I had more difficulties).

Comment: In this post I've edited our arithmetic function as *\pi_{_{R}}(x)*  I say it if you want to use this notation in your answer (explore my formulas with the right bottom of the mouse choosing first *Show Math As*, and after *TeX Commands*)

Comment: If it is required to add references to the post, as references for the Second Hardy–Littlewood conjecture or Ramanujan primes, I can to add a comment about it.

Comment: Many thanks for your help @DavidG.Stork

Comment: **All users,** the numerical evidence that I got, that is very small was for the following statement: *we've that* $$\pi_{_{R}}(x+y)\leq \pi_{_{R}}(x)+\pi_{_{R}}(x)+1\tag{1}$$
*for all integers* $2\leq x,y\leq 120$. I cann't improve more this since my programming skills aren't the best. If some user can to improve my computational evidence for $(1)$, for an integer greater than $120$ add a comment. On the other hand I'm waiting what about mathematical reasonings about my question, and this evidence in this commment. Many thanks.

Comment: I hope that my computational evidence in previous comment is right, it is appreciate if some user can to add numerical/computational evidence for this or other of my unanswered questions.